# Push Notifications - registerForRemoteNotification FAILED

Tags: xcode, push, registration

I tried to get my app ready for Push Notifications, I insert the following code in the app delegate but when I running the App on my Device (iPhone 3Gs - iOS 5.1.1) the app start's normal but whiteout the "Push Alert" how asks the user to allowed notifications!!!

Can someone help??

Best regards from Germany!

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new appID in the iOS Provisioning Portal (without a wild-card character) like

com.yourcompanyname.yourappname

and enable push notifications for this app id.
Then create a new provisioning profile which you use to build your app. It should work then!
Be sure to change you bundle id in your project settings too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, now the alert is poping up!
But now I become the following Error: There is no device token stored yet. (Code: 115, Version: 1.0.67)

Comment: you should probably take a look at Apples documentation. Where do you get the error? Did you implement the delegate methods in your appDelegate?